# Recover data from raid 1 when both drives are faulty

Tags: data-recovery, raid, raid1

I had a RAID 1 on my server, and apparently both of hard drives have failed at the same time.

Server support did a quick check to confirm that

```
HDDTEST-W1F21M6K    ERROR   Finished (Selftest, Device: sda); 
HDDTEST-W1F22Y9M    ERROR   Finished (Values-Check, Device: sdb);

However, there still seems to be a partition table on sdb.
Your server is currently booted into our rescue system. Please try 
to backup your data if possible and contact us again if 
you wish to proceed with a hard drive replacement.
```

I'm able to boot the system from other drive and see the following structure

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md3 : active raid1 sdb4[1]
     1822442815 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1]
  1073740664 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
  524276 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1]
  33553336 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
```

What I need is to be able recover some important data from the `/dev/md2` partition. I'm trying to mount md2 and getting the following:

```
mount /dev/md2 /mnt

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md2,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

*Update 1*

Some more data

```
mdadm -E /dev/sdb3
/dev/sdb3:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
Feature Map : 0x0
 Array UUID : 39c5b7f5:c3bed499:e383ce7f:0868fc3e
       Name : rescue:2  (local to host rescue)
Creation Time : Wed Feb  6 07:23:32 2013
 Raid Level : raid1
 Raid Devices : 2

Avail Dev Size : 2147481600 (1024.00 GiB 1099.51 GB)
 Array Size : 1073740664 (1024.00 GiB 1099.51 GB)
Used Dev Size : 2147481328 (1024.00 GiB 1099.51 GB)
Data Offset : 2048 sectors
 Super Offset : 8 sectors
      State : clean
Device UUID : 3d68ec1a:3b125641:fa4b1d34:c829f017

Update Time : Wed Aug  6 13:21:28 2014
   Checksum : dad4eccc - correct
     Events : 18773099


 Device Role : Active device 0
 Array State : A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

*Update 2*

Volumes available

```
ls /dev/sd
sda   sdb   sdb1  sdb2  sdb3  sdb4  sdb5  

mdadm -E /dev/sda
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda.
```

dmesg output after mount /dev/md2 /mnt attepmt

```
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x600fffff SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] ata2.00: cmd 60/08:e8:70:3b:d4/00:00:43:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq 4096 in
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014]          res 41/40:08:70:3b:d4/00:00:43:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014]         43 d4 3b 70 
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] Read(16): 88 00 00 00 00 00 43 d4 3b 70 00 00 00 08 00 00
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1137982320
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:12 2014] ata2: EH complete
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:15 2014] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 1134
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:15 2014] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 1134 in log
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:16 2014] JBD2: recovery failed
[Wed Aug  6 16:11:16 2014] EXT4-fs (md2): error loading journal
```

*Update 3*

for sdb

```
smartctl -d ata -A /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.14.10] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   101   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       216425892
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   095   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       6
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   092   092   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       10928
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   081   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       149168536
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   085   085   000    Old_age   Always       -       13145
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       6
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   064   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       12885098499
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   067   052   045    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 26/36)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       17084
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   033   048   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (0 22 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       504
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   097   097   000    Old_age   Offline      -       504
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       128896263532923
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       10152724077
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       40689314539
```

and for sda

```
smartctl -d ata -A /dev/sda
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.14.10] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Error SMART Values Read failed: Input/output error
Smartctl: SMART Read Values failed.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
```

Comment: Please post `mdadm -E /dev/sda3` and `mdadm -E /dev/sdb3`. Also, `dmesg` around the time of that failed mount.

Comment: The one for `sda3` as well, please. Need to make sure they both died around the same time...

Comment: There is no sda3 in my /dev/ directory, only sdb*. I have posted updated output above.

Comment: As for dmesg - i'm doing all this from recovery console (that was booted after drives have failed, so i can't get that neither)

Comment: Ok, there is no `/dev/sda` at all? Also, I mean, check `dmesg` in your recovery console, see if it got some errors when you tried that `mount` which gave 'wrong fs type, ...'.

Comment: Yes, there is just sda, i have posted details above

Comment: And I guess it couldn't find a partition table on /dev/sda? `fdisk -l /dev/sda` gives blank and/or errors? (Also check `dmesg` for errors from that). Basically, curious which I/O errors you're getting in dmesg. That'll tell if the next step is finding a way to copy the data off, except for a few bad sectors or if the next step is sending to a data recovery firm.

Comment: Oh, also, that appears to be SATA... What does `smartctl -d ata -A /dev/sdb` say? Same with `/dev/sda`, I suppose.

Comment: `fdisk -l /dev/sda` returns nothing, and btw - thanks for helping! :)

Comment: added `smartctl` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it'd appear that `/dev/sda` is very dead, and you're not going to get data off it, at least not without tricks.

`/dev/sdb` on the other hand just seems to have a lot of bad sectors. That's probably a bad sign for it, but you should be able to get your data off.

Depending on how important the data is and how confident you are in your backups, you'll want to first image the disk, at least the sectors that can be read. Tools include GNU ddrescue, and a few more similar programs.

Then fsck. E.g., `fsck /dev/md2` to do it on the live system. You can try with `-p` first to automatically fix errors where its pretty sure the risk is minimal, or with `-y` to tell it to fix everything (even if its risky). Or without any options, and it'll prompt you for each thing.

After that, you should be able to mount `/dev/md2` and get your data, or at least what remains of it, off.

I would ask your hosting company to retain the two failed disks for a little bit (after replacing the disks) until you're sure you have all of your data.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a proper backups of the data - i believed that raid 1 with 2 hard drives won't fail at the same time (shame on me) :) I will try to do a `fsck /dev/md2` now. Or does it make sense to create an image of whole volume first ?

Comment: @SergeSamusya I suspect they didn't really fail at the same time, you probably just didn't notice when the first one failed... Also, RAID is not a backup. It'll perfectly happily mirror that mistaken `rm -Rf` to the other disk, instantly.

Comment: @SergeSamusya BTW: When you get your server set back up, make sure the mdadm monitor daemon is running, and run `/sbin/mdadm --monitor --test --scan -1` and make sure that test alert gets delivered to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advices. Doing `fsck /dev/md2` helped me! :) Now volume is mounted and i'm copying data. Will try to be more careful in future

Comment: @SergeSamusya glad to hear you're getting your data back!